# Is it possible to display a video (webcam) stream from a non-browser-app in a browser (using WebRTC)?

Tags: .net, video-streaming, webrtc

I'd like to stream a webcam video/sound from within a .NET app (WPF) to display it in a browser.

For the browser side I know WebRTC is great for video chats with another browser.

But is it also possible when one end is no browser?
How would I have to send the video/audio then from within the .NET app so that the browser can display it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can look at my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45675274/how-to-to-make-a-peer-connection-with-a-native-desktop-win-application/45732066#45732066

Comment: https://avspeed.com has a sdk for .net wpf and windows forms - can also be used in a web app

Answer (score -1):

One possible solution is to use CefSharp (http://cefsharp.github.io/) as a WebBrowser-Control within your application, since the common .NET WebBrowser-Control is based on IE which does not support WebRTC.