# how to to make a peer connection with a native desktop (win) application

Tags: c#, webrtc

I need to make a peer connection with a native desktop (win) application and a webbrowser , just to transfer raw data. And in theory WebRTC seems to be the only way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use WebRTC to exchange data between a browser and a desktop, you can code the desktop part into C# language using this library : http://www.meshcommander.com/webrtc (poor support and documentation, only data channel implemented, but free and functional).

Edit : There is also this .Net library with support of video : https://github.com/radioman/WebRtc.NET

Also, you can write the desktop part using Node.js. There are a lot of WebRTC libraries on the web and you w'll have more documentation and support.